# Problem with nested for loop with zip() function, Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a piece of code like this:

```
items1 = ['col1', 'col2']

items2 = ['a', 'b']
items3 = [1, 2]
data = zip(items2, items3)

for col in items1:
    print(col)
    for d in data:
        print(d)
```

and the output is:

```
col1
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
col2
```

It's like the for loop in 'data' works just once.
My expected output was some:

```
col1
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
col2
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
```

It works if I invert the loops in the nested structure, like:

```
for d in data:
    print(d)
    for col in items1:
        print(col)
```

whose output is:

```
('a', 1)
col1
col2
('b', 2)
col1
col2
```

printing out all the information but not preserving the order, as I would like to.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion and I am sorry in case the format of the question was not compliant with the site rules (this is my first question here).

Comment: you may be looking for `data = list(zip(items2,items3))`  the `zip` is an iterator that runs out once it's exhausted, it's not reusable

Comment: This kind of thing is why you're supposed to call `zip` when you need it, rather than trying to save the return value in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most (if not all) iterators can only be traversed once. The reason this seems confusing is that you are accustomed to iterating over lists, but lists are *not* iterators. They are *iterable*, because you can get an iterator for a list. A `for` loop implicitly calls `iter` on a list, but you can do so explicitly as well.

```
itr = iter([1,2,3])  # itr is a value of type list_iterator


# Fully consumes itr, outputting
#
#   1
#   2
#   3
for x in itr:
    print(x)

# Produces no output, because there is nothing left in itr to iterate over
for x in itr:
    print(x)
```

If you want to iterate over the result multiple times, you either need to call `zip` each time,

```
for col in items1:
    print(col)
    data = zip(items2, items3)

    for d in data:
        print(d)
```

or create a list from the `zip` object first.

```
data = list(zip(items2, items3))
for col in items1:
    print(col)
    for d in data:
        print(d)
```

Answer (score 3):

zip produces an iterator. You use it up once and it's gone. Instead you can store it into a container such as a list, so you can iterate over it as many times as you want.

```
items1 = ['col1', 'col2']
items2 = ['a', 'b']
items3 = [1, 2]
data = list(zip(items2, items3))

for col in items1:
    print(col)
    for d in data:
        print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that this was one of the big changes between Python 2 and Python 3.  In Python 2, `map`, `zip`, `range`, `filter`, `keys`, `values`, `items` all returned lists.  In Python 3, they return iterators.

If you are used to Python 2, this can be confusing at first.